# Очередная возня с кодировками и JSP

Tags: java, jsp, unicode

Всем привет! Сегодня делая сайт с помощью Java и фреймворков столкнулся с очередной непонятностью.
У меня есть jsp страничка там обычная таблица без стилей и форма для заполнения.
Решил я руссифицировать заголовок у страницы jsp

на русские буквы (киррилицу)

```
<h1> Тест <h1>
```

браузер этого не понял, погуглив я добавил

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Перезапустился и воаля, заголовок на русском, отлично, подумал я и приступил к заполнению формы на страничке "русскими буквами".
Сделал submit и в таблице получаю вместо понятных русских слов вот такое "Ð¢ÐµÑ?Ñ?Ð¸Ð½Ð³".

Хотя до того как я добавил:

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

всё было нормально при submit!
Опять погуглил, нашёл как править конфиги my.cnf под определённую кодировку, выполнив всё по инструкции ни чего не помогло.

Использую: 
DB Mysql  
IDE Idea  
OS Linux mint  
Framework spring

Comment: А попробуйте фильтр добавить с перекодировкой. https://dertompson.com/2007/01/29/encoding-filter-for-java-web-applications/

Comment: @carapuz Спасибо! Всё работает теперь.